# Firestore query by geohash and ordering by date

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I am trying to make a firestore query to fetch data that is based on geohash and in order of date (shown below).

```
  query = db
    .collection('activities')
    .where('geohash', '>=', bounds[0][0])
    .where('geohash', '<=', bounds[0][1])
    .orderBy('geohash')
    .orderBy('postedOn', 'desc')
    .limit(queryLimit);
```

However, my query seems to only retrieve based on geohash and not in order of date. I am assuming this may be limitation to firestore. I have thought about combining geohash and date field to be sorted on same field, but that wont work in my case.

Is my query set up wrong? If not, any alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since you first order on `geohash` and only then on `postedOn`, the results are first sorted on `geohash` and only on `postedOn` for documents that have the same geohash value (which likely is uncommon). This is the expected result for this type of query.

If you want to show the results in a different order, you'll have to resort the results in your application code.

Comment: If I wanted to retrieve 100 documents that is within certain geohash and postedOn date, what can I do? If I retrieve only geohash filtered data, then I would not get latest documents even on the client side.

Comment: There's no way to perform a range filter (like `>` and `<`) on two different fields. The only think you could try is find a way to merge the fields, which is essentially what geohashes already do with the latitude and longitude values of a location. If you want to learn more about this, I gave a talk about it a couple of years ago https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q But the answer may be that you need to perform two queries and then merge them in your application code.

Comment: Do you think creating a field of both geohash + datePosted would help here? For example, 'dr5rukk2u4' + '20221116' format would be persisted. When querying, I can query start coordinate + certain date in the past and end coordinate + today's date. In this way using one range filter,  I can accomplish to order by geohash and datePosted.

Comment: After watching the video, I understood the concept around geohash filtering; however, it still doesnt answer my original question of filtering by geohash and by date. I know firebase cannot support this specific usecase, then does that mean I would need to use third party database just to satisfy this usecase?

Comment: If Firestore can't meet your needs, it makes sense to look for another solution indeed.

Comment: Is this aggregation query something that firestore is going to support in the near future? I would hate to migrate to another solution.

Comment: Not that I know of.